# Failed to load resource "font"

Tags: css, fonts

I got this error on my site: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` while trying to load my font.

This is the only thing I got for code. I don't know what else should i do in order to load a font.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'aharoni';
  src: url("aharoni.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

link: http://ondiversion.net/vialighting/

Comment: loading.gif is also giving a 500.

Where do you host those two files?

Comment: Following is the error observed in Browser Console: `downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "aharoni" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): status=2147746065 source: http://ondiversion.net/vialighting/css/aharoni.ttf`

Answer (score 0):

This **error500** also concerns your `loading.gif` and `favicon.ico` so this is not only about the fonts.

Depending on your hosting, there is a few different cases which could cause this issue.

The most common concerns the **.htaccess rights**.
I would bet on this in your case.

You should have a look on "[why-am-i-getting-a-500-internal-server-error-message](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644990/why-am-i-getting-a-500-internal-server-error-message)".

Good Luck'

Comment: Yes but is the way I uploaded the font correct? so everything is in line but the problem might be the htaccess?

Comment: The way the font is uploaded is correct, considering the information I have.